# Show the ASCII code of each character in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In T-SQL, how to show the ASCII code of each character in a string?

Example of a string:

```
Adrs_line1
ABCD
```

I would like to show this:

```
Adrs_line1_ASCII
65|66|67|68
```

Currently, I do this (I increment the number manually):

```
ASCII(SUBSTRING(Adrs_line1, 1, 1))
```

The all purpose of this is to find which character break an address.
Because this code doesn't work for 5% of the addresses :

```
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(ADDRESSSTREET, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '.'), 3) as Adrs_line1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(ADDRESSSTREET, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '.'), 2) as Adrs_line2,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(ADDRESSSTREET, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '.'), 1) as Adrs_line3,
```

EDIT :

More information about my problem :

In our ERP, the address is shown with return carriage (line 1, line 2 and line 3). But in the database, the three lines are concatened in one string. So, I have to seperate the three lines by detecting the character that do the return carriage. Normally is char(10) or char(13), but for 5% of the adresses, it's another character that I can't find manually.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [`ASCII`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function?

Comment: Just cast it to `varbinary` if you just want to see the character codes (though they will be in hex rather than decimal). e.g. `select cast('ABCD' AS varbinary(100))` gives `0x41424344`

Comment: Yet another https://xyproblem.info/. What do you really want to achieve? What would be your input and what is the expected output?

Comment: I've added more information about my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something you might be able to use and adapt.

Create a table-valued function that will return any deemed "bad" characters:

```
create or alter function dbo.FindBadAscii (@v varchar(max))
returns table as
return
  select v [Char], Ascii(v) [Ascii] 
  from (
    select top (Len(@v)) Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) n 
    from master.dbo.spt_values 
  ) d
  cross apply(values(Substring(@v, d.n, 1)))x(v)
  where Ascii(v)<32 and Ascii(v) not in (9,10,13)
```

You can then test it like so:

```
select * from dbo.FindBadAscii ('a' + Char(10) + 'b' + Char(20) + 'c')
```

This identifies any "control" characters that are not a tab/lf/cr

Result

> 20